# Query different in Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a sentence like this:

```
return this.db.collection('places', ref => ref.where("CodPais", "!=", pais)).valueChanges();
```

but neither != nor <> are valid. Is it possible to do it in some way?

Answer (score 0):

The `where()` method takes three parameters: a field to filter on, a comparison operation, and a value. The comparison can be `<, <=, ==, >, or >=`. For iOS, Android, and Java, the comparison operator is explicitly named in the method.

[Click here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to read the Firebase documentation about this.